# How do I setup my Osoyoo touchscreen?

Tags: screen, touchscreen

I bought an Osoyoo touchscreen for my Raspberry Pi. I tried a lot of methods to get it working but I couldn't get the screen working. I followed these methods:

[I found this PDF file but it didn't work](http://osoyoo.com/wp-content/uploads/samplecode/rasp_lcd.pdf)

[This also didn't work](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/)

How can I set the screen up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find separate driver for Osoyoo screen. They only provide OS image. If you **really** need this screen working you can download image from [here](http://osoyoo.com/driver/rpiscreen.php) and write it to SD card (f. e. using dd). Otherwise I recommend to use something more common (that has normal drivers).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this is fairly old but if anyone is still looking for this. Theres a github with all the different drivers and install instructions.

https://github.com/mfcardenas/OsoyooTFT

Comment: Anyone know how to rotate the display? I still have not figured that out :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but depending on your version you can get the raspberry pi image, but I contacted the manufacturer and they sent me a link for the drivers for v6.2 at the following link:

http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_2.tar.gz

but you can also find the remaining drivers at :

http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

EDIT:
For completeness you can find the Raspbian Images with drivers included at:

http://osoyoo.com/driver/rpiscreen.php